# How to Calculate Minimal Log Discrepancy on a Toric Variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, toric-varieties

Let $\sigma$ be a $3$ dimensional strongly convex rational polyhedral cone on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $X_\sigma$, the corresponding affine toric $3$-fol. Also, assume that $\Delta$ is an anti-boundary $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor on $X_\sigma$, i.e., $\Delta \geq 0$ and $K_{X_\sigma}-\Delta$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier.

Now, how do I calculate the Minimal Log Discrepancy of the pair $(X_\sigma, \Delta)$ in terms of the minimal ray generators of the cone $\sigma$ ? Is there any criterion for this?

Comment: Maybe you should look at Ambro's paper "On minimal log discrepancies". In section 4 there is a formula.